# PowerShell Newb - Cannot convert

Tags: powershell

I'm learning Powershell and I'm trying to understand why this isn't working. I verified that -Identity accepts pipeline so I'm guessing its the type of value its passing but I don't understand why this doesn't work

Get-ADUser -Identity (Import-Csv .\GROUP.csv)

GROUP.csv is a file on my desktop which contains a list of SIDs. I can read it with no issues when just doing an Import-Csv .\GROUP.csv. Here is the result

### S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-112088

S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-48881
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-48880
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-53776
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-125569
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-120374
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-48882
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183175
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183136
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183130
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183112
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-176034
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-176023
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-176022
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-176002
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175974
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175931
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175889
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175836
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175804
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183195
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-183180
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-31219
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-176037
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-82576
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175905
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175777
S-1-5-21-583907252-1979792683-725345543-175765

On top of that I can use the Get-ADUser -Identity  and that works fine.

Why do I get the following when trying piping the one to the other?

Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. 
Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:22
+ Get-ADUser -Identity (Get-Content .\group.txt)
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Answer (score 1):

The `-identity` parameter doesn't accept `array` as input but it accept `pipeline` input by `value` than you can do:

```
Import-Csv .\GROUP.csv | Get-ADUser
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the first column in .csv file is **sid** then you can try this option too

```
 (Import-CSV .\Group.csv) | foreach-object { get-aduser -Identity $_.sid }
```